# how to create MySQL Query which will add row data in column while inner joining two tables

Tags: mysql, pivot, inner-join

I have two tables, I want to make inner join in a specific way mentioned below

I have **Read access to DB** so Can not use **Declare, set or create** function

SQL Code provided at bottom to create below tables

Table 1

| Mechanic | Car Part Repaired |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | Engine |
| Joe | Wheels |
| Joe | Lights |
| Ross | Mirror |
| Ross | Brakes |
| Chandler | Door |

Table 2

| Mechanic | Time (Hrs) |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | 16 |
| Ross | 12 |
| Chandler | 50 |

Expected Result should be as below

| Mechanic | Time (Hrs) | Car part 1 | Car Part 2 | Car Part 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 16 | Engine | Wheel | Lights |
| Ross | 12 | Mirror | Brakes | NA |
| Chandler | 50 | Door | NA | NA |

I want to join above tables in a way it will not create additional rows and will have equal row as Table 2, So I can perform the calculation on table 2 data and get correct results.
On other hand want to pivot the "table 1.Car Part" values into columns, for eg.,

Joe has 3 values in car part column (Engine, wheel, Lights) , so these 3 values should get transform into 3 columns.

No. of values should be equal to no. of additional columns

SQL Query to create above tables

```
CREATE table #Table_1
([Mechanic] varchar(18), [Car_Part] varchar(18));

INSERT INTO #Table_1
([Mechanic], [Car_Part])
VALUES
('Joe', 'Engine'),
('Joe', 'Wheels'),
('Joe', 'Lights'),
('Ross', 'Mirror'),
('Ross', 'Brakes'),
('Chandler', 'Door');

CREATE table #Table_2
([Mechanic] varchar(18), [Time_Hrs] int);

INSERT INTO #Table_2
([Mechanic], [Time_Hrs])
VALUES
('Joe', 16),
('Ross', 12),
('Chandler', 50);
```

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: It seems to me that you are using SQL Server not MySQL as `[]` aren't allowed in MySQL.

Comment: Hello @ErgestBasha I never add data in DB so dont have any idea, I just have read access, but sure it is MySQL. Also above tables are for reference, Original data is different which I am working with